# (Bad file descriptor error) Pipe between a execl() C and a Python in Python program

Tags: python, c, linux, pipe, exec

I tried to exchange a string between Python and C programs using a pipe(), but I got nothing.
After that I tried to exchange a string between two C programs using a pipe() and everything was fine.

Python parent program:

```py
import os


def main():
    r, w = os.pipe()
    pid = os.fork()

    if pid == 0:
        os.close(r)
        print('fd =', w)
        name = '/home/subado/tmp/pipes/c'  # compiled c.c
        os.execl(name, name, str(w))
    else:
        os.close(w)
        os.waitpid(-1, 0)
        print('Parent receive: ', os.read(r, 10))
        os.close(r)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Child c.c program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  if (argc < 2) {
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  char buf[] = "1000 - 7?";
  int fd = (int)strtol(argv[1], (char **)NULL, 10);
  printf("fd = %d\n", fd);
  ssize_t count = write(fd, buf, sizeof(buf));
  if (count == -1) {
    perror("write");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  } else {
    printf("Child send: %s\n", buf);
  }
  close(fd);
  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Python parent program output:

```
fd = 4
fd = 4
write: Bad file descriptor
Parent receive:  b''
```

But when I wrote same parent program in C:

```c
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
  int pipefd[2];

  if (pipe(pipefd) == -1) {
    perror("pipe");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  pid_t cpid = fork();
  if (cpid == -1) {
    perror("fork");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  if (cpid == 0) {
    close(pipefd[0]);
    printf("fd = %d\n", pipefd[1]);
    const char *child = "/home/subado/tmp/pipes/c"; // compiled c.c
    const int ENOUGH = (int)((ceil(log10(pipefd[1])) + 1) * sizeof(char));
    char str[ENOUGH];
    sprintf(str, "%d", pipefd[1]);

    execl(child, child, str, NULL);
  } else {
    close(pipefd[1]);
    int statloc;
    waitpid(-1, &statloc, 0);
    char buf[10];
    read(pipefd[0], buf, sizeof(buf));
    printf("Parent receive: %s", buf);
    close(pipefd[0]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Now output is:

```
fd = 4
fd = 4
Child send: 1000 - 7?
Parent receive: 1000 - 7?
```

Can someone explain why I got the `Bad file descriptor` error?

What the difference between C and Python parent programs?
I don't understand why my Python code doesn't work.

Solution:
I added the

```py
os.set_inheritable(w, True)
```

before

```py
os.execl(name, name, str(w))
```

This fixed my code due to the fact that the file
descriptors returned by the `os.pipe()` are non-inheritable by default.
Thanks [dimich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14772619/dimich)!

Comment: `chr(w)` does not do what you think it does. You need `str(w)`.

Comment: It does exactly what I want. If it did something unexpected, then `fd` in child and parent processes would be different.

Comment: Open a Python interactive session, and do `chr(123)`. It will result in the string `'{'`. Do you really want to pass a string like that to the child process? Oh I see in your C program that you make the (false) assumption that the pipe descriptor is guaranteed to be a single digit. That's just not true. Convert it to a *string*, and in the C program convert that string to an integer.

Comment: Just a gut feeling, but what happens if you switch place between the `waitpid` call and the `print` statement in your Python script, what happens then?

Comment: Ok. I understand you but in this case it doesn't matter, because the file descriptor actually always a single digit.

Comment: I switch `waitpid` and `print`. I get this:

~~~
fd = 4
Parent receive:  b''
fd = 4
Child send: 1000 - 7?
~~~

Comment: By the way, you have very little error checking. What does `write` return in the child program?

Comment: I modified child C program and output is the same(check program in question).

Comment: I don't call a python script using `excel`. I call the compiled c.c program. I use an absolute path to exclude ambiguity.

Comment: Read [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) for `os.pipe()`: *Changed in version 3.4: The new file descriptors are now non-inheritable.*

Comment: Thank you so much! I fixed my code with `os.set_inheritable(w, True)` before `os.execl(name, name, str(w))`

Comment: Subado @dimich somebody should make that an answer

Comment: @erik258 Сreated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

According to `os.pipe()` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.pipe):

> Changed in version 3.4: The new file descriptors are now non-inheritable.

This means file descriptor is closed in child processes at the execution of a new program.

You can make descriptor inheritable with `os.set_inheritable(w, True)`.